# How to update a dataframe with values from another dataframe when indexes and columns don't not match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update the dataframe `df` with the values coming from another dataframe `df_new` if some condition hold true.

The indexes and the columns names of the dataframes does not match. How could it be done?

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'val': [10, 10, 10],
}, index=names)

new_names = ['a', 'c', 'd']
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'profile': [5, 15, 22],
}, index=new_names)

above_max = df_new['profile'] >= 7

# This works only if indexes of df and df_new match
#df.loc[above_max, 'val'] = df_new['profile']

#  expected df:
#    val
# a   10
# b   10
# c   15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for match index values of mask with another DataFrame:

```
s = df_new['profile'].reindex(df.index)
above_max = s >= 7
df.loc[above_max, 'val'] = s
```